# Can three.js accept data from REST APIs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, rest, three.js

I am learning three.js. I have created simple 3D models using hardcoded parameters. My next step is to load the values from a database that I created in MSSQL Server. The x, y and z parameters are stored in a table named dimensions. My question is can I connect three.js with REST API (developed in SpringBoot or Node.js) that API will fetch the data from my DB and pass it to my three.js project which will render the object at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't really dependent on three.js for that. You can create your API in Spring or Node, then in your client code (three.js), you can use something like `fetch` or `ajax` to actually call that API. Once you get a response, you can simply call functions that set appropriate values.

Comment: Can you please share some resource which explains how to fetch from API in three.js? It will be really helpful for me

Comment: Again, the use fetch and ajax is not at all specific to three.js. Fetch is a feature that javascript provides natively. Here's a good resource: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data